# form & ajax script mix up

Tags: php, ajax

I've got this chat system on one of my pages which uses ajax to auto update itself every 10 seconds. I also have a normal html form. The ajax request sends for a file called `chatAjax.php` and the form sends data to `process.php`

If the user submits the form before the timer is up the system works normally. However for some reason if the user takes a while to enter the data the data gets sent and then the user lands on `chatAjax.php` instead of going back to the main page. I have no clue what is going on and `process.php` has no references to `chatAjax.php`. So why do they end up on `chatAjax.php`?

Here is the ajax script:

```
function refresh(){
        var ajaxRequest;

        try{
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                document.getElementById("Chats").innerHTML= ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajaxRequest.open("POST", "chatAjax.php", true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
        setTimeout("refresh()",10000);
    }
```

if you want a further look just go to http://www.cogtek.co.cc/community.php (thats the main page I was talking about)

Comment: why do you send data to two different urls? please show us some code, especially your ajax call

Comment: chances are that this comes from an error in the chat system code, post at leas your configuration (initialization) of the chat system js, and maybe parts of it if it's not a classic library.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

In my process.php script I would record what page I came from and then return to that page. It seems as though the ajax script overwrites this and the script would make it go to the wrong page. I have now set the part of the process.php script to now only go to community.php.